# Google Assistant voice search is slightly modifying my search queries

Tags: google, voice-command, google-assistant, google-search, voice-typing

Has anyone else noticed when voice searching with Google Assistant it'll sometimes change your query slightly but to a question you didn't ask?

This is not a simple case of mis-hearing spoken words; Google is trying to be smarter than me by changing my search query to idiot-proof it.

One example of many I've experienced:

- Asked google: "How to disable 'Application X' from starting with  MacOS Boot"
- Search field populated with and results showing for: "'Application X' will not start."

Not what I asked, and this happens frequently.

Is this a preference, is there any way to turn this off?

Any thoughts appreciated.